# Не уживаются вместе лого и элементы навигации

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Существует проблема: есть `nav`, в котором лого и элементы навигации, однако, уживаться вместе они ну никаким образом не хотят!

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
p,
a,
div,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'TTNorms_Regular', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* HEADER ================= */

.header-main {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #FDEAA8;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: max-content;
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo-image {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar ul {
  width: 500px;
}

.navbar li {
  height: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-main">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="calculator-logo"><img class="logo-image" src="images/calc-logo.png" alt=""></a>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Калькуятор</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Переводчик</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Взлом жопы</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
ознакомьтесь. а то сейчас это:
- у тебя есть код?
- лучше! у меня есть скрин кода!

Comment: @redale исправил, извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере лучше дописать пару стилей.. (в CSS, после комментария `/* Добавлено */`)

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
p,
a,
div,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'TTNorms_Regular', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* HEADER ================= */

.header-main {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #FDEAA8;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: max-content;
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo-image {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar ul {
  width: 500px;
}

.navbar li {
  height: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Добавлено */

.navbar::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.navbar > a,
.navbar > .nav-list {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.navbar > a {
  width: 80px;
}

.navbar > .nav-list {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

```html
<header class="header-main">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="calculator-logo"><img class="logo-image" src="images/calc-logo.png" alt=""></a>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Калькуятор</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Переводчик</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Взлом жопы</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

А ещё лучше, почитать о таких возможностях "компоновки", как [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) или [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

Comment: Флексы и гриды, тоже блочная.. Данный способ называется, вроде, инлайновый. Не сказал бы что он старый и использовать его не нужно.. Но зачем усложнять, когда есть выше указанные технологии)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<header class="header-main">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="calculator-logo"><img class="logo-image" src="images/calc-logo.png" alt=""></a>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Калькуятор</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Переводчик</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Взлом жопы</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

```css
.navbar{
displey:flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}
.calculator-logo{
display: inline-block;
}
.calculator-logo img{
width: 50px;
height: 70px
}
.nav-list{
display: flex;
}
```

ну и так далее....